# C++ Exceptions: Don't getting any exception

Tags: c++, exception

Well, I've just started to learn Exceptions at college, here is a code that is supposed to throw an exception if an introduced value is out of a range stablished by me...
Thinking and analizing, I think there might me an error with the throws, and some guy tell me in other question that indeed I have not declared any throw...I may have stupid mistakes so sorry for the trouble
Here is my code:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <exception>


class ExcepcionRango : public std::exception{
protected:

    ExcepcionRango::ExcepcionRango(){
    }
public:
    virtual const char* lanzarExcepcion()=0;

};

class ExcedeRangoInferior : public ExcepcionRango{
public:
    ExcedeRangoInferior::ExcedeRangoInferior(){
    }
    const char* lanzarExcepcion() throw(){ //throw exception
        return "Value out of minimal range";
    }
};

class ExcedeRangoSuperior : public ExcepcionRango{
public:
    ExcedeRangoSuperior::ExcedeRangoSuperior(){
    }
    const char* lanzarExcepcion() throw(){ //throw exception
        return "value out of maximal range";
    }
};

int obtainValue(int minimo, int maximo){ //obtain value

    int valor; //value
    std::cout<<"Introduce a value between "<<minimo<<" and "<<maximo<<" : "<<std::endl;
    std::cin>>valor;
    return valor;

};

int main(){
    ExcedeRangoSuperior* exS = new ExcedeRangoSuperior();
    ExcedeRangoInferior* exI= new ExcedeRangoInferior();
    int min=3; 
    int max=10;
    int valor=0; //value
    try{
        valor=obtainValue(min,max);
        if(valor<min){

            throw exS->lanzarExcepcion();
        }
        if(valor>max){

            throw exI->lanzarExcepcion();
        }
    }catch(...){
        std::cout<<"Exception: ";
    }

    delete exS;
    delete exI;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

PD: the functions lanzarExcepcion() are supposed to throw the message if the inserted value is out of range

Comment: You are not seeing any message because you are only `cout`ing "Exception"

Comment: What message are you getting?

Comment: nrhine1 It was that, of course I wasn't calling any of the exception class functions, I've just fixed it

Comment: You're doing he whole exception thing wrong. You should throw an actual instance of the _class_ not a string. I.e. `throw ExcedeRangoSuperior()`, then override [`std::exception::what`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/what) to return a descriptive string. To catch that error, you use `catch (ExcedeRangoSuperior &error_superior)` Also, in your own answer you use exceptions for correct values as well, which is wrong. Exceptions are for _exceptional_ events, i.e. errors.

Comment: Now I get it, I thought I was doing it right but I didn't. Thanks! I guess I need to re-fix the code again and see what happens!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using exceptions in the wrong way, I decided to "refactor" your code to show how it's most usually done:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

class ExcepcionRango : public std::exception
{
protected:
    ExcepcionRango::ExcepcionRango()
        { }
};

class ExcedeRangoInferior : public ExcepcionRango
{
public:
    ExcedeRangoInferior::ExcedeRangoInferior()
        { }

    const char *what() const
    {
        return "Valor fuera de rango inferior";
    }
};

class ExcedeRangoSuperior : public ExcepcionRango
{
public:
    ExcedeRangoSuperior::ExcedeRangoSuperior()
        { }

    const char *what()
    {
        return "valor fuera de rango superior";
    }
};

int obtainValue(const int minimo, const int maximo)
{
    int valor; 
    std::cout << "Introduzca un valor entre " << minimo << " y " << maximo << " : " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> valor;

    if (valor < min)
        throw ExcedeRangoInferior();
    else if (valor > max)
        throw ExcedeRangoSuperior();

    return valor;
};

int main()
{
    const int min = 3; 
    const int max = 10;

    int valor;

    try
    {
        valor = obtainValue(min, max);
    }
    catch (ExcepcionRango &exc)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << exc.what() << std::endl;
    }

    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I have more clear the Exceptions thing. I was clearly wrong

Comment: @JoséDelValle Sounds like this is the answer you should accept.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't do what you think it does.

```
void fn() throw();
```

Does NOT say "the function fn throws an exception."  It says: the function fn will **NEVER** throw an exception (and if it would, your program will immediately call `terminate()` and end.  It's unlikely you want that.)

Instead, you use the `throw` keyword with a value as part of a statement in a function:

```
void fn()
{
    ExceptionRango e;
    throw e; // or just "throw ExceptionRango();"
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        fn();
    }
    catch(ExceptionRangoInferior &e)
    {
        // Caught an exception of type ExceptionRangoInferior
    }
    catch(ExceptionRango &e) 
    {
        // Caught an exception of type ExceptionRango (or a subclass thereof
        // which isn't ExceptionRangoInferior because that was already caught
        // above
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        // Caught an exception of an unknown type
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Well I've fixed it, now it works!

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <exception>


class ExcepcionRango : public std::exception{
protected:

    ExcepcionRango::ExcepcionRango(){
    }
public:
    virtual const char* lanzarExcepcion()=0;

};

class ExcedeRangoInferior : public ExcepcionRango{
public:
    ExcedeRangoInferior::ExcedeRangoInferior(){
    }
    const char* lanzarExcepcion() throw(){ 
        return "Valor fuera de rango inferior";
    }
};

class ExcedeRangoSuperior : public ExcepcionRango{
public:
    ExcedeRangoSuperior::ExcedeRangoSuperior(){
    }
    const char* lanzarExcepcion() throw(){
        return "valor fuera de rango superior";
    }
};

int obtainValue(int minimo, int maximo){

    int valor; 
    std::cout<<"Introduzca un valor entre "<<minimo<<" y "<<maximo<<" : "<<std::endl;
    std::cin>>valor;
    return valor;

};

int main(){
    ExcedeRangoSuperior* exS = new ExcedeRangoSuperior();
    ExcedeRangoInferior* exI= new ExcedeRangoInferior();
    int min=3; 
    int max=10;
    int valor=0; 
    try{
        valor=obtainValue(min,max);
        throw valor;

    }catch(int){
        if(valor<min){

            std::cout<<"Exception: "<<exI->lanzarExcepcion();
        }
        if(valor>max){

            std::cout<<"Exception: "<<exS->lanzarExcepcion();
        }
        if(valor>min && valor<max){
            std::cout<<"Valor correcto"<<std::endl;
        }
        std::cin.get();
    }

    delete exS;
    delete exI;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: -1: _Please_, for the love of God, consider @Joachim Pileborg's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11045456/21567) and [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043578/c-exceptions-dont-getting-any-exception#comment14447601_11043578).

Comment: I haven't noticed his answer at the time I read dirkgently's answer. Maybe I've been doing the things wrong but thanks, and thanks to @Joachim too for his useful answer